# How to remove a JavaScript component (object)

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

So I have a very basic game and I need a "Restart" button to work instead of refreshing the game to restart the game. When I click the button I want to remove everything and then load the main function again, however the objects are not removed.

The objects:

```
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
    myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
```

The code I've tried to use to remove the components:

```
    myObstacles.clear();
delete myObstacles[i];
delete myObstacles();
```

What actually happens is that I restart everything except the components so they keep on duplicating instead of being removed and then generated again once the main function is started.

Other topics related to this didn't help me get a working result. Your help is truly appreciated!

Comment: So, you want to clear the `myObstacles` array or do something more than this?

Comment: Why you need to delete and create a new Object? You can make a method on that Object as init() where to set the values to default ones and just call the method to reset all object properties.

Comment: `delete` does not do what you think it does.